# How to group multiple WHERE clauses in brackets to get more accurate results

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a table that stores user info. I am trying to get a match from the table if 3 different conditions are met. The conditions worked separately but not working when grouped, though all the conditions are true. The SQL statement has 3 different conditions;

1. several OR conditions in brackets
2. two AND conditions in brackets
3. one condition in bracket.

This is the statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId 
FROM userinfo_table 
WHERE ((questionName IN("cars") AND intValue & 3) OR
       (questionName IN("farms") AND intValue & 3) OR
       (questionName IN("pets") AND intValue & 5)
      ) AND
      (questionName="birthdate" AND 566092800<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateValue)7 7 <=1572480000) AND
     (userId <> 3)
LIMIT 0, 20
```

`condition 1` is:

```
(questionName IN("cars") AND intValue & 3) OR (questionName IN("farms") AND intValue & 3) OR (questionName IN("pets") AND intValue & 5)`
```

condition 2 is

```
 questionName="birthdate" AND 566092800<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateValue)<=1572480000`
```

condition 3 is 
    userId <> 3

Please am I wrong with the brackets? Or what am I not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the parentheses.  The problem is that you want to compare values on different rows for the same `userId`.  You cannot do that with a simple `WHERE` clause.

This is your query as I interpret it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId
FROM userinfo_table
WHERE ((questionName IN ('cars') AND intValue & 3) OR
       (questionName IN ('farms') AND intValue & 3) OR 
       (questionName IN ('pets') AND intValue & 5)
      ) AND
      (questionName = 'birthdate' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateValue) <= 1572480000
      ) AND
      userId <> 3;
```

(condition 2 is unclear in your question).

Clearly, no row can satisfy all conditions, because `questionName` would have to have more than one value.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT userId
FROM userinfo_table
WHERE ( ((questionName IN ('cars') AND intValue & 3) OR
         (questionName IN ('farms') AND intValue & 3) OR 
         (questionName IN ('pets') AND intValue & 5)
        ) OR
        (questionName = 'birthdate' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateValue) <= 1572480000
       )
      ) AND
      userId <> 3
GROUP BY userId
HAVING SUM(questionName = 'birthdate') > 0 AND  -- at least one birthdate record
       COUNT(DISTINCT questionName) > 1;        -- at least one other matching record
```

EDIT:

Oh, I think I figured out condition 2.  You cannot write it like that (well, you can, but it doesn't do what you think it does.)

```
SELECT userId
FROM userinfo_table
WHERE ( ((questionName IN ('cars') AND intValue & 3) OR
         (questionName IN ('farms') AND intValue & 3) OR 
         (questionName IN ('pets') AND intValue & 5)
        ) OR
        (questionName = 'birthdate' AND
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateValue) >=  566092800 AND
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateValue) <= 1572480000
       )
      ) AND
      userId <> 3
GROUP BY userId
HAVING SUM(questionName = 'birthdate') > 0 AND  -- at least one birthdate record
       COUNT(DISTINCT questionName) > 1;        -- at least one other matching record
```

Comment: Good, :) I gave it a try and it worked. Thanks so much :)